# JMeter 5.5 and Java 17 .... on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9"

Tags: jmeter

An error occurred: 'java.util.Vector org.apache.commons.cli.avalon.CLArgsParser.getArguments()'

I am getting this error... and I am not able to open Jmeter

Which is the best Java version to use with Jmeter 5.5 on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9?

many thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

JMeter 5.5 works fine with Java 17...

The problem was that I have inadvertently deleted a file from the folder

lib/ext..

[image]